# What information do I need to find to solve this kinematics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

The question is this:

> As you look out of your dorm window, a flower pot suddenly falls past. The pot is visible for a time $t$, and the vertical length of your window is $L_w$. Take down to be the positive direction, so that downward velocities are positive and the acceleration due to gravity is the positive quantity $g$.
>   Assume that the flower pot was dropped by someone on the floor above you (rather than thrown downward).
>
> From what height $h$ above the bottom of your window was the flower pot dropped? Express the answer in terms of $L_w$, $t$, and $g$.

I haven't been able to get anywhere with this problem. I know that the total distance is $h$ (the height above the window) and the vertical length $L_w$. How should I approach this problem?

Edit: So I wasn't able to get the problem right on my homework assignment, but now I have the correct answer, which is:

$$h={{L_w}^2\over 2gt^2}+{gt^2\over 8}+{L_w\over 2}$$

I cannot for the life of me figure out how this is the correct solution. Why is this the answer and how is it done?

Comment: I had trouble posting an answer so I'll put in what I was writing (I think it was put on hold while I was typing ...)

Comment: Part 1:

Hi Grace.

Again, it is a home-worky question so I'll just try to steer you in the right direction - the previous answer may have you moving in the wrong direction since you are after the height, and the answerer assumed you wanted the time elapsed.

Here's one way to attack the problem: you know from conservation of energy that the kinetic energy of the flower pot when it's at the bottom of the window ($\frac{1}{2}mv_f^2$) is equal to the gravitational energy it has acquired since being dropped $mgh$.

Comment: part 2:

Combining these equations, you should be able write the height $h$ in terms of the final velocity $v_f$.

Of course you don't know $v_f$, but you **do** know the time $t$ and the distance $L$. You also know [several equations which relate these things](http://zonalandeducation.com/mstm/physics/mechanics/kinematics/EquationsForAcceleratedMotion/EquationsForAcceleratedMotion.htm). Using these equations and the relationship between gravitational and kinetic energy above, you will arrive at the answer stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will split this question up in to two parts. First it will be useful to figure out how fast the flower pot is going when it passed by the bottom of the window. Secondly from this velocity you can derive at which time/position its velocity should have been zero and thus when or from where it has been dropped.

For the first part we know that after the pot enters the top of the window it takes $t$ seconds until it leaves the bottom of the window, which lies $L_w$ meters below the top of the window. In order to distinguish between the visible time $t$ and the time variable in the [kinematics equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics#Particle_trajectories_under_constant_acceleration), I will use $\tau$ as the time variable. This can be written as the following equations,

$$
y(\tau) = y_0 + v_0 \tau + \frac g 2 \tau^2,
$$

where $y_0$ and $v_0$ are the vertical height, of the pot relative to a chosen reference height, and velocity respectively at $\tau = 0$, such that

$$
y(\tau_1) = y(\tau_0) - L_w,
$$

$$
\tau_1 = \tau_0 + t.
$$

Usually it will be simpler to set $\tau_0$ and $y_0$ to zero, such that you only have to solve for $v_0$. With this solution for $v_0$ you can find the velocity at the bottom of the window $v(\tau_1) = v_0 + g \tau_1$.

From this velocity $v(\tau_1)$ there are various ways of deriving the height, from which the pot was dropped. You could formulate another kinematics equation and go back in time until the velocity is zero, but in this case conservation of energy will be easier and faster, namely gravitational potential energy was converted to kinetic energy.

Hopefully this offers enough guidance to derive the final given expression in the answer, if not feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a homework style question I will only point you in the right direction.

Create a $y$ axis and label the important distances $0$, $h$ and $L_w$, as in the diagram below:

[image: Window problem diagram.]

The pot starts falling from $y=0$ at $t=0$ and will reach the top of the window at $t_1$ and the bottom at $t_2$, the difference $t_2-t_1$ is the time you are seeking.

Because the pot experiences the gravitational acceleration $g$, we know that:

$y=\frac{gt^2}{2}$.

From this, calculate $t_1$ and $t_2$ for the relevant values of $y$, then $t_2-t_1$.